# Java Stream : How to filter conditionally?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following stream statement with Java Stream and I filter records based on the typeId values as  `types.getIds().contains(x.getType().getId())`:

```
return petRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(x -> types.getIds().contains(x.getType().getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getType().getName(), Collectors.counting()));
```

However, I want to fetch all values when `types.getIds().size() == 0` and tried something as shpon below:

```
.filter(types.getIds().size() > 0 ? x -> types.getIds().contains(x.getType().getId()) : <NO FILTERING>)
```

So, how can I skip filtering when `types.getIds().size() == 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
return petRepository.findAll().stream()
            .filter(x -> types.getIds().isEmpty() ||
                         types.getIds().contains(x.getType().getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getType().getName(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. I concluded `.filter(pet -> types.getIds().isEmpty() ? true : types.getIds().contains(pet.getType().getId()))` that seems a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @ferry Ternary expressions should never use boolean literals. You should use Thomas' `||` formulation.

Comment: Hmmm, then I switch to that solution, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to check for empty on every `x`, you can put the whole lambda in a ternary expression:

```
return petRepository.findAll().stream()
            .filter(types.getIds().isEmpty() ? x -> true 
                    : x -> types.getIds().contains(x.getType().getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getType().getName(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Or pop the stream in a temporary variable and apply the entire `filter()` conditionally:

```
Stream<X> stream = petRepository.findAll().stream();
if (!types.getIds().isEmpty()) {
    stream = stream.filter(x -> types.getIds().contains(x.getType().getId()));
}
return stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getType().getName(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Yes: It sounds like the most efficient solution

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. I concluded `.filter(pet -> types.getIds().isEmpty() ? true : types.getIds().contains(pet.getType().getId()))` that seems a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remember that the predicate in the `filter` has to return true whenever you want a result to be included. So in your case the filter condition must be such that, if the ids are NOT empty, filter will only return true for the condition you want. If the ids are empty, then filter must always return true.

You can play with this by writing a minimal test example (or better yet, mocking your petRepository with junit or another testing framework).

Consider:

```
Set<Integer> ids = Set.of(2);
List<Integer> elements = List.of(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list = elements.stream()
        .filter(u -> ids.size() > 0 ? ids.contains(u) : true)
        .toList();
System.out.println(list);

// output here will be [2]
// but if ids is empty it will be [1, 2, 3]
```

Look at what's inside `filter`: `ids.size() > 0 ? ids.contains(u) : true`

If there are ids to check, see if the streamed element of `elements` is contained in them. If there are no ids to check, return true regardless (keep everything in the elements stream for the next step in the pipeline).

The ternary expression in this case could be further simplified to `u -> ids.size() <= 0 || ids.contains(u)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. I concluded `.filter(pet -> types.getIds().isEmpty() ? true : types.getIds().contains(pet.getType().getId()))` that seems a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @ferry a ternary expression with `true` or `false` in either value expression can be simplified using `||` and `&&`. In this case: `types.getIds().isEmpty() || types.getIds().contains(...)`